# Keycloak permission information product Ids

Tags: jwt, access-token, keycloak

We use keycloak as IAM solution. We have several customers who need access to certain products. Is the information on which product the user is allowed to access stored in the keycloak system or do I have to store the information elsewhere? My fear is that if I store 1000 productIds in the user token the will be very large and must send again and again to the server.

Comment: You should be using  fine-grained authorization  https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/